# Pandas idiom for attaching a predictions column to a dataframe

Tags: indexing, pandas, dataframe, statsmodels

What is the Pandas idiom for attaching the results of a prediction to the dataframe on which the prediction was made.

For example, if I have something like (where `qualityTrain` is the result of a `stats models` `fit`)

```
qualityTrain = quality_data[some_selection_criterion]
pred1 = QualityLog.predict(qualityTrain)
qualityTrain = pd.concat([qualityTrain, pd.DataFrame(pred1, columns=['Pred1'])], axis=1)
```

the 'Pred1' values are not aligned correctly with the rest of `qualityTrain`. If I modify the last line so to reads

`...pd.DataFrame(pred1, columns=['Pred1'], index=qualityTrain.index)...`

I get the results I expect.

Is there a better idiom for attaching results to a dataframe where the dataframe's may have an arbitrary index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do

```
qualityTrain['Pred1'] = pred1
```

Note that we're (statsmodels) going to have pandas-in, pandas-out for predict pretty soon, so it'll hopefully alleviate some of these pain points.

Comment: This works to fix the problem here, but I have another that is related and that mystifies me: [why does `predict` return an un-indexed array](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22580477/656912)?

Comment: Because it was written before pandas existed and we haven't updated it yet.